# Dynamic style using variable substitution

Tags: geoserver, sld

I need to use an array of values to define a style of the WMS dynamically. I understood that I must use the [Variable substitution SLD](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html).

I'm be able to use `env` variable to change fill and stroke of a polygons layer and set one unique color to all the features.

Problems comes when I try to classify that polygons using the value field from DB table.

Using the SLD below I can see a gradient of color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>Inhabitant</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Inhabitant</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0 - 0 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0 - 0 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#f7fbff</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0 - 0,19 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0 - 0,19 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.19230637850000004</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#e2eef9</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0,19 - 1,03 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0,19 - 1,03 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0.19230637850000004</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1.03380595443000001</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#cde0f2</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>1,03 - 2,71 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>1,03 - 2,71 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1.03380595443000001</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2.70682544712000039</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#b0d2e8</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>2,71 - 6,15 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>2,71 - 6,15 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2.70682544712000039</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>6.15129542350000058</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#89bfdd</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>6,15 - 13,28 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>6,15 - 13,28 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>6.15129542350000058</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>13.28059577942000047</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#60a6d2</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>13,28 - 30,18 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>13,28 - 30,18 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>13.28059577942000047</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>30.17719783778998632</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#3e8ec4</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>30,18 - 53 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>30,18 - 53 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>30.17719783778998632</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>52.99988479614005854</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#2172b6</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>53 - 92,18 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>53 - 92,18 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>52.99988479614005854</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>92.17585220336999896</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#0a549e</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>92,18 - 790,77 </se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>92,18 - 790,77 </se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>92.17585220336999896</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>790.77160644529999445</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#08306b</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

My aim is reproduce this using `env` variable but I don't have clear where I need to put that variable.

I've tried this:

```
      <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:Function name="env">
          <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
```

but I see this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for
> PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer myself, this is the solution:

```
  <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
    <ogc:And>
      <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Function name="env">
            <ogc:Literal>minimum</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
      <ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Function name="env">
          <ogc:Literal>maximum</ogc:Literal>
          <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
      </ogc:PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
    </ogc:And>
  </ogc:Filter>
```